# jdbc mysql configuration in jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

> String tenant_code="qh_I01_";
> String varResult = tenant_code + (vars.get("GET_COMP_CODE"));
> log.info(varResult);
> vars.put(varResult);
>
> how to get the varResult in jdbc url?
> jdbc:mysql://12.12.121.178:3306/${varResult}

Comment: any update on this ? If answer was helpful it should be accepted so that it 's useful to others

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your 4th line:

```
  vars.put("varResult", varResult);
```

But what you are trying to do cannot work because:

- JDBC Connection Configuration is initialized on Test Start , meaning it will be when varResult is empty, so you would get this in URL  **jdbc:mysql://12.12.121.178:3306/**
- Beanshell Post Processor will only run after any sampler in its scope

Comment: I did in the same way vars.put("varResult", varResult); but it showing 'No database selected'

Answer (score 0):

below is the screenshot of test plan structure.

[image]

Comment: you should put this in your question

Comment: I understand @UBIK LOAD PACK, thanks for advice. Unfortunately amit was not able to paste this image in his question, so i did. I hope its fine, i will be glad if you help us solving the actual issue. :)

Comment: I answered your question